# Half of Classic ASP page works great, 2nd half gives SQL connection error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic, iis-7, shapes

Please help!

I am moving a Classic ASP & ASP.Net website from one server to another, and one of the reports that works fine on the old server is only partially working on the new server.

**Can someone please tell me:**

- If there is anything that might be preventing a successful connection to SQL server.
- If there is anything else involved in the this than:

  - Connection String
  - ASP Page
  - DLL

**My server environment:**

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- SQL EXPRESS 2008
- IIS7

**Connection Details:**

The Classic ASP pages of this website connect using a SQL connection string located in the registry. The other Classic ASP pages on the website are working just fine....and the first half of this report is also working just fine.

I have tested the connection string individually, and it connects properly.

**Report Structure Details:**

The first half of the report (that is working correctly) loads data directly from a table in the database to display each item in a list format. It also uses the EMPLOYEES table to populate the employee name for each item in the list.

The second half of the report (that is NOT working) loads data from the same table as the first half. However, it groups them by manager (Manager Details are stored in the EMPLOYEES table).

So, both half of the reports are accessing the same tables for information....the only difference is how they are displayed.

**Error Details**

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server->DLL.Shape_DB.ShapeCMdWithRS(SHAPE {select * from employees where username in (select mgr_username from employees where empID in (select empID from time_off_requests where mgr_code=0)) order by last_name, first_name} APPEND ([select time_off_requests_view.*, employees.mgr_username as username from time_off_requests_view inner join employees on employees.empID = time_off_requests_view.empID where mgr_code=0} relate username to username) as timeoff, ...)@WEBSITENAME[version 4.0.480] error '80004005'

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

**Code Details**

Here is the CLASSIC ASP code for the part of the website that **DOES** work:

```
set time_off_requests = DLL.TimeOffAdminPending()
%>
<CENTER>

<%
if time_off_requests.EOF then %>
<font class="headerNoBold">No Pending Time Off Requests<BR>

<%  else %>

<font class="headerNoBold">Pending Time Off Requests</font>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="500" align=center border=0 bordercolorlight=#000000 bordercolordark=#000000>
<TR bgcolor=#ffffcc>
    <TD width=33% align=center><B>Date</B></TD>
    <TD width=33% align=center><nobr><B>Requested By</B></nobr></TD>
    <TD width=33% align=center><nobr><B>Type</B></nobr></TD>
</TR>
<% 
dim theDate
do while not time_off_requests.EOF 
if (time_off_requests.AbsolutePosition mod 2) = 0 then %>
            <TR bgcolor=#ffffcc>
        <% else %>
            <TR bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <% end if %>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center>
            <A HREF="time_off_request_details.asp?timeoffreq_id=<% = time_off_requests("timeoffreq_id") %>">
            <% = time_off_requests("dt_created") %>
            </A>
        </TD>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center><% = time_off_requests("last_name") %>,&nbsp;<% = time_off_requests("first_name") %></TD>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center><% = time_off_requests("time_off_type") %></TD>
</TR>
<%      
    time_off_requests.MoveNext
    loop %>
</TABLE>
<%  end if %>
```

**Details from the DLL**

```
Function TimeOffAdminPending() As ADODB.Recordset

TimeOffAdminPending = RunCmdWithRS("select * from time_off_request_view where mgr_code =0 and empID in (select empID from employees where mgr_username = '" & username & "')")

End Function
```

Here is the CLASSIC ASP code for the part that **DOES NOT** work:

```
<%  set managers = DLL.PendingTimeOffMgr()
if not managers.EOF then %>
<font class="headerNoBold">Pending Manager Time Off Approvals</font>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="500" align=center border=0 bordercolorlight=#000000 bordercolordark=#000000>
<TR bgcolor=#ffffcc>
    <TD width=33% align=center><B>Date</B></TD>
    <TD width=33% align=center><nobr><B>Requested By</B></nobr></TD>
    <TD width=33% align=center><nobr><B>Type</B></nobr></TD>
</TR>
<%  do while not managers.EOF
    set time_requests = managers.Fields("timeoff").Value %>
<TR><TD colspan=3>
        <% = managers("last_name") %>, <% = managers("first_name") %>
</TD><TR>
<% 
do while not timeoff_requests.EOF 
if (timeoff_requests.AbsolutePosition mod 2) = 0 then %>
            <TR bgcolor=#ffffcc>
        <% else %>
            <TR bgcolor=#ffffff>
        <% end if %>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center>
            <% = timeoff_requests("dt_created") %>
        </TD>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center><% = timeoff_requests("last_name") %>,&nbsp;<% = timeoff_requests("first_name") %></TD>
        <TD class="smallText" align=center><% = timeoff_requests("timeoff_type") %></TD>
</TR>
<%
    timeoff_requests.MoveNext
    loop
    managers.MoveNext
    loop %>
</TABLE>
<%  end if %>
```

**Details from the DLL**

```
PendingTimeOffMgr() As ADODB.Recordset

PendingTimeOffMgr = ShapeCmdWithRS("SHAPE {select * from employees where username in (select mgr_username from employees where empID in (select empID from time_off_requests where mgr_code = 0)) order by last_name, first_name} APPEND ({select time_off_requests_view.*, employees.mgr_username as username from time_off_requests_view inner join employees on employees.empID=time_off_requests_view.empID where mgr_code = 0} relate username to username) as timeoff")

End function
```

Comment: You're using a datashape query.  Are you using a datashape connection string - see here. https://connectionstrings.com/msdatashape/

Comment: No I'm not using a datashape connection string. We weren't using one on the original server either, so I'm not sure why this report was working on there. I'll give it a try and see if this resolves it.

Comment: I've changed the connection string to a DataShape Connection String, and I am still getting the exact same behavior. Here is my new connection string:

Comment: Provider=MSDataShape; Data Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=System; User ID=System; Password=password